# Dividir matrices

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Dividir matrices es equivalente a multiplicar la primera por el inverso de la segunda.
Por qué entonces si :

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
B = np.array([[6,2],[1,2]])
A @ np.linalg.inv(B)
```

Que resulta en:

```
[[0.  1. ]
[0.2 1.8]]
```

Es diferente de:

```
A * (1/B)
```

Que resulta en.

```
[[0.16666667 1.        ]
 [3.         2.        ]] ????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque los operadores `*` y `/` no hacen lo que piensas.

`1/B` no es la inversa de `B`, sino que *elemento a elemento* calcula C[i,j] = 1/B[i,j], como puedes observar:

```
>>> B
array([[6, 2],
       [1, 2]])

>>> 1/B
array([[0.16666667, 0.5       ],
       [1.        , 0.5       ]])
```

0.166666 es 1/6. 0.5 es 1/2.

Análogamente `A*B` tampoco hace la multiplicación de matrices, sino la multiplicación *elemento a elemento* de las matrices, es decir, C[i,j] = A[i,j]*B[i,j]. Ambas matrices deben tener las mismas dimensiones.

Una vez comprendido lo anterior, se ve que `1/B` no es la inversa de `B` ya que de hecho `(1/B)*B` no produce la matriz unidad, sino otra en la que todos los elementos son unos.

En cambio `np.linalg.inv()`, sí que te da la inversa de la matriz, y `@` sí que calcula el producto de matrices, por lo que `B @ np.linalg.inv(B)` sí producirá la matriz unidad (1 en la diagonal, 0 en el resto).